# iOS - truly persistent data?

Tags: ios5, persistence

I'm exploring a business model that specifies how many times a (costly) function may be invoked per user in an application.

Right now whatever I save, e.g. user defaults, gets deleted when the app is deleted. When the app is reinstalled, the counter is back to zero.

What I need is a way to save information such that deleting the app still leaves the information intact.

I've seen examples that mimic the deprecated unique identifier, but that's per device, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: What kind of app is this? Is this a game? Are users required to have an account (I guess not from your post)?

Comment: @nhahtdh Business oriented. I've just reviewed KeyChains, it can be used to store small amounts of data separate from the app sandbox.

Comment: If you can enforce user to create an account on your server, for example, then you can also maintain the service even if the user deletes the app, and also provide the service on multiple devices. (I found out that you can't use user's apple ID, and device UUID is deprecated from iOS 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KeyChains appear to be the right way to go. I can store a unique ID there specific to the user as well as in the user defaults and that way can track also if the app was reinstalled.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that still per-device? Also, it depends how strongly you want to stop users bypassing your limit but fundamentally, *nothing* from the client should be trusted. Is there any way you can store the count server-side?

Comment: @Basic It's per device, but a unique ID will be created, so in most cases it's per user. As long as iOS devices are single user, no problems there. If the device transfers to someone else, then it will most likely be wiped, so a new ID will be created. I'll keep the ID client- and server-side, but most other data server-side.

Comment: What if a user has multiple devices? Or is that not a concern? You did  say "but that's per device, which is not what I'm looking for."

Comment: It was a solution that used the Mac Address and some other ID to always generate the same ID per device, no matter who owns it. A random ID that persists will suffice. If they own multiple devices, the user can bypass the limitation, will have to let it go. Don't really want to get into creating accounts because it just adds more problems.